# Why joomla doesn't use relation views and foreign keys?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, database

As it's obvious, `joomla` doesn't use relation views and foreign keys. It seems that everything is handling in the application level (not in the database).

For example, a reference value can be deleted , and still the foreign key can exists! It violates the databases rules. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla tables were initially built on MyISAM database engine of MySQL which does not support foreign keys.

Recent versions of Joomla! switched to InnoDB engine which supports foreign keys/views however to keep backward compatibility there are no foreign keys introduced.